# Pandas Duplicate A Row When Date in Column Exists and Delete Date in Original Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv with an identifier and three columns that could contain a date or could be null. If the column contains a date. I need to make a copy of that row and delete the date from the original row.

Original and Desired result:

[image: Orignal and Desired result]

I've tried the following(which I found here on stackoverflow) and I am duplicating Date1 successfully but I'm not sure where to start on deleting the date from the original row. I am currently just making a copy of the whole row.

```
is_term = employeeDF['Date1'] > '0'
employeeDF_try = employeeDF[is_term]
employeeDF2=employeeDF.append(employeeDF_try)
```

Any help is appreciated, I'm pretty new at this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This looks like a pivot. Have you tried with pivot solution?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew - I have not tried a pivot yet but will look into it. Thank you!